# Vue.js 3's alternative to `Vue.config.errorHandler`

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, airbrake

Airbrake's [Vue configuration](https://airbrake.io/docs/installing-airbrake/installing-airbrake-in-a-vuejs-app/#configuration) page is still about Vue 2:

```
Vue.config.errorHandler = function (err, vm, info) {
  airbrake.notify({
    error: err,
    params: {info: info}
  });
}
```

What is the equivalent for Vue.js 3?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's the same in [vue 3](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#errorhandler) with a little change which is the use of Vue instead (instance of createApp()) instance of `Vue` class :

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

let app=createApp(App)

app.config.errorHandler = function (err, vm, info) {
  airbrake.notify({
    error: err,
    params: {info: info}
  });
}
app.mount("#app");
```